# Determine all m parameter values for which the domain of the function are all real numbers

Tags: rational-functions

The function is:

$$ f(x) = \frac{2x}{mx^2 + 1} $$

The answer sheet says the answer is: $ m \ge 0 $ but I don't get it. My answer was $ m \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \{-1, 1\}  $, because then, when $x=1$ or $x=-1$ the denominator may come out as $0$. Would anyone care to explain?

Comment: In the real domain, $mx^2+1$ does not show any root if $m \geq 0$. If this is not the case, $f(x)$ would have vertical asymptotes at $x=\pm \frac 1 {\sqrt {-m}}$.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Did you mean $\pm\frac1{\sqrt{-m}}$?

Comment: @ajotatxe. Thanks for pointing the typo ! Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $m\geq 0,$ $mx^2+1\geq 1,$ so the denominator is never $0$, and the formula makes sense on all of $\mathbb{R}$.

For $m<0$, $mx^2+1=0$ for $x=\sqrt{-1/m},$ which is now a real number, since $m$ is negative. Hence, the above formula cannot be defined for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$ for $m<0$.